# How do i set todays date in datepicker with usage of data-binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, data-binding

Currently i'm using a datepicker:

```
<DatePicker Name="dpEmailConfirmed1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" SelectedDate="{Binding EmailConfirmation}" Margin="5"/>
```

Now i would like to set the datepicker as default to todays date.

All articles i read so far, are using "SelectedDate" for the setting. But in my case i'm using it with a binding to a model, to get the chosen date.

Can i do another way?

I trid already

```
<my:DatePicker DisplayDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

and

```
dpEmailSent1.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
```

and

```
dpEmailSent1.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
```

Comment: The binding is alright, if `EmailConfirmation` is a `DateTime` instance. What exactly does not work? If you bind to the `EmailConfirmation` property, then set it to the current date in your view model.

Comment: @thatguy: Yes EmailConfirmation is a DateTime instance. Currently it sets the date after launch to 01.01.0001.

Comment: That is the **default** value of the `DateTime` struct. Just set this `EmailConfirmation` property to the date that you want on construction / initialization, e.g. `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding of the [`SelectedDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate?view=netcore-3.1) property is correct. Instead of setting the default value in XAML, assign it to the bound `EmailConfirmation` property in your view model, e.g. in its constructor:

```
public class MyEmailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MyEmailViewModel()
   {
      EmailConfirmation = DateTime.Today;
   }

   private DateTime _emailConfirmation;
   public DateTime EmailConfirmation
   {
      get => _emailConfirmation;
      set
      {
         if (_emailConfirmation.Equals(value))
            return;

         _emailConfirmation = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   // ...other view model code.
}
```

Since you want to apply the date of today, you can use [`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netcore-3.1) instead of [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netcore-3.1) to reset the time component of the instance.

Also do not forget to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) e.g. like in the example above, otherwise changes to the property will not be reflected in the user interface.